# Jenkins job that runs on Jenkins node(slave) fails after pulling changes from VisualSVN

Tags: jenkins, svn, visualsvn-server, svnkit

I have a job that run on on Jenkins node(lets call it X) in a restricted network has firewalls restrictions and does not allow communication using all ports(only 22,443,80) so our **Jenkins Master uses port 443 to communicate with the node.The communication works and jobs run on this node.**

I am then **trying to pull code from visualSVN server which uses a self signed certificate, the jenkins job will run successfully if there are no changes in the code,**

**However if there are some changes, it will pull them(changes get added in slaves workspace) and then job fails with error as in image.**

I use the checkout strategy:Use SVN update as much as possible.but i get same error if i use check out fresh copy.

so if i run the job it fails because there are some changes to be pulled.but it pulls then.now if i run the job it will be successful.very unstable behaviour.
I ran SVN commands from CLI on agent it works and i added certificate permanently when it asked the first time.

Kindly help

Console output from jenkins:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXMMU.png

Comment: The image is missing. BTW, it's a good practice to post error wordings in text format.

Comment: HI @bahrep please check the image i have added thanks

Comment: Isn't your Jenkins version outdated? Make sure that it is up to date and update its SVN plug-in. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin Don't forget to make sure that VisualSVN Server version is up to date, too. If you use VisualSVN Server 3.4.x or older, upgrade to the latest 3.6.x version.

Comment: @bahrep we are using jenkins LTS version and SVN plugin is upto date.

Comment: @bahrep we are using jenkins LTS version and SVN plugin is upto date.VisualSVN is 3.3.1 and due to client restriction we cannot upgrade it.Any other workaround.Thanks Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

1. VisualSVN Server 3.3.x version family is not supported since 31st December 2016. You must upgrade to the latest release family. Today it is VisualSVN Server 3.6. Don't forget to read the article [KB103: Upgrading to VisualSVN Server 3.6](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00103/) before upgrading.
2. There are no reasons to use outdated server or client version. Moreover, newer and older SVN clients are compatible. You can use newer VisualSVN Server version even if by some unknown reason you have to outdated SVN clients.
3. The problem that you've encountered is caused either by a bug in Jenkins - [Jenkins SVN plug-in to be precise](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) - or firewall and antivirus. It is also possible that there are problems with the network that result in these errors.